# i am getting an error that says must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args);
    string name, state;
    double quantity, unitPrice;
    double sales, tax;
    public static double computeTax(double sales, string state) {
        double taxMultiplier = 0;
        if (string.Compare(state, "NY", true) == 0) {
            taxMultiplier = 0.04;
        } else if (string.Compare(state, "NJ", true) == 0) {
            taxMultiplier = 0.07;
        } else if (string.Compare(state, "FL", true) == 0) {
            taxMultiplier = 0.06;
        }
        return sales * taxMultiplier;
    }
    public static double computeTotal(double quantity, double price) {
        return (double) quantity * price;
    }
    public static void Main() {
        string name, state;
        System.Console.Write("Enter the name of the customer: ");
        name = System.Console.ReadLine();
        System.Console.Write(" In which state (NY / NJ / FL) ?: ");
        state = System.Console.ReadLine();
        System.Console.Write("How many items were purchased?: ");
        string input;
        input = System.Console.ReadLine();
        int numItems = System.Convert.ToInt32(input);
        System.Console.Write("What was the unit price of the items?: ");
        input = System.Console.ReadLine();
        double price = System.Convert.ToDouble(input);
        double totalSales = computeTotal(numItems, price);
        System.Console.WriteLine("Total Sales for " + name + " are: $" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", totalSales));
        double taxAmt = computeTax(totalSales, state);
        System.Console.WriteLine("The Tax Amount is: $" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", taxAmt));
        double totalWithTaxes = totalSales + taxAmt;
        System.Console.WriteLine("The total with taxes is: $" + string.Format("{0:0.00}", totalWithTaxes));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: it is really hard to help you, this is a full example of how a question should not be asked

Answer (score 0):

start by removing the following, which is declaring a method without a body:

```
static void Main(string[] args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this:

```
static void Main(string[] args);
```

You need a function body.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to solve this issue simply by removing the following line which is invalid.

```
static void Main(string[] args);
```

If you are purposely including two entry points for your application (that line is actually supposed to be used as another method), you must include a method body for the line above. So remove the semi-colon and add a method body:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Do something in here
}
```

Note that you will also have to specify the entry point in the compiler using `/main` (when there are multiple entry points available). You can do this in your project options if you are using Visual Studio.

Comment: ok i did that, but now it is saying i need to "Compile with/main to specify the type that contains the entry point." on the public static void Main() part.

Comment: @AdamMinter: As I said, you will need to specify which entry point to use in your project settings. At this point it sounds like you don't need multiple entry points, so you can remove that line entirely.

Answer (score 0):

in .NET, an executable can have only one entry point i.e. only one Main method is allowed. To be more specific, the Main method is considered as an entry point only if the sigature matches any of the below 2 and the method is static.

1. Main(String[])
2. Main()
   If, you provide a main method whose signature is different from above two, it is not considered as Main method. So, below code is allowed,

Example

```
class Program
{
        static void Main ()          //Entry point
        {
        } 

        static void Main(int number)
        {
        }
}
```

The below code doesn't compile because, it finds matching signature at two places.

```
class Program
{
        static void Main ()          //Entry point
        {
        } 

        static void Main(String[] args)   //another entrypoint!!! Compile Error
        {
        }
}
```

Below code also doesn't compile because there is no entry point at all,

```
class Program
{
        static void Main (int a)      //Not an Entry point 
        {
        } 

        static void Main(float b)    //Not an entry point
        {
        }
}
```

Note: taken from MSDN forums